# Why is Kane tormenting Trent throughout the movie?

Tags: in-the-mouth-of-madness

In *'In the Mouth of Madness'*, Sutter Kane keeps playing with Trent's mind, with his teleporting car trick, causing Linda to go insane, annoying creepy townspeople, etc.

However it turns out that

> Trent was a character written by Kane the whole time, that everything that happened in Trent's day to day life was whatever Kane wrote, and Trent did didn't really matter anyway as it could all be predestined by Kane.

Moreover, when Trent tries to go rough at the end by

> destroying Kane's manuscript, Kane writes Trent so that Trent has already delivered the manuscript months ago to the publisher and the book was in fact already at stores.

If Kane could do all this anyway, why was he tormenting Trent throughout the movie? Why was it so important for Trent to deliver the manuscript himself if Kane could make it happen by just writing it in?

Comment: I think the fact that the storyline doesn't seem to make sense is part of the point.  In particular, whatever forces Trent finds himself up against act according to their own utterly inscrutable motives.